# Can I externally view the progress of my Python program running in the background?

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I have a Python program that can take several days to finish running on my cloud-hosted Ubuntu machine. At it's current stage, I can only see the progress of the program only if I keep my shell open. `print("processed: " + str(finalCount) + " files.")` -- simple and straightforward.

Since learning [of this trick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396654/how-to-run-the-python-program-in-the-background-in-ubuntu-machine), I thought that it would be great if I can check the progress of the program without having to open the shell and find the process using `ps -e`

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I have a couple ideas, but I'm not sure how viable they are (since performance is paramount. These programs can run from days to weeks). The first idea would be to set up a very simple MySQL database that would be updated each time a task is finished performing. Not sure how much strain that would put on the server, however--or if this is even an efficient idea.

Second idea: have the program append it's status to a simple log file. Then if I'm curious, I can simply download the current version of the log file.

Any thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python have a standard library named [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#module-logging). It can record the progress while program running. Those logs can be outputted as a log file. You can [try it](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Database will not be very good idea for this usecase.

Use [python logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module to log the status/progress of your task, it very light-foot and won't be much of an issue if you are not updating/logging very fast.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured that setting up an entire database was a bit overkill.  Thanks for the suggestion, I will check out python logging!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in an [answer linked to the question you cite](https://askubuntu.com/a/106359/315347), you can use GNU screen to  keep track of a long running process. I use it frequently for long running processes and wrote a [blog post with the most common command arguments](http://paulremote.blogspot.fr/2014/11/gnu-screen-for-long-running-server.html).

Start a screen session with:

```
    screen -S sessionname
```

In order to find the screen session later give it a name using sessionname. Start a long running process. Then detach the session with:

```
    CTRL-A-D
```

You can re-attach the session later with:

```
    screen -r sessionname
```

In parallel, writing to a text log sounds like a good idea. Have a look at the official documentation explaining [how to write log files with python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html).